# Telnet reader will split input after 1448 characters

Tags: telnet

I am writing a java applet that will print what a telnet client sends to the connection. Unfortunately, the client splits at 1448 characters.

The code that is proving to be a problem:

```
char[] l = new char[5000];
Reader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream(), "US-ASCII"));
int i = r.read(line);
```

I cannot change the source of what the telnet client reads from, so I am hoping it is an issue with the above three lines.

Comment: What do you mean by "splits"? It's not clear what your actual issue is. Are you getting the data the client sent or not? This code is probably fine, the issue is probably in the code that tries to make sense out of the data sent. Where's that code?

Comment: I have the above code in a while loop, so the first time, line will be set to something like "The cat ran across th" and the second time around, line will be set to "e road." The strings, of course, would be longer than that, however. It is always 1448 characters, though.

Comment: Great, you're getting the data correctly. Now you need to write code to make sense of it. Nothing 'glues' characters together, they're just a stream. It's up to you to make sense of the data you receive, following the rules of the protocol that you are implementing.

Comment: The issue is the length of the read in line. I would prefer it to read "The cat ran across the road." than "The cat ran across th" then in the next iteration, "e road."

Comment: So write code that does that. The "it" that does that is not *this* "it". This "it" just reads the data. That's all it does. If you want to assemble the data into larger chunks, then write code to do that. The issue is simply that you haven't written any code to glue chunks of bytes together yet. You have to actually *implement* the protocol to get protocol data units out because it's the protocol that defines with a protocol data unit *is*. You haven't done that yet, so you are asking for the impossible.

Comment: Ah, I think there's a misunderstanding. Everything is all written concerning that. I'm just making a client that reads it. The client as a whole works, except it splits up the output into blocks. Later down the line, it writes what line says and does all sorts of fun things with it. I am just wondering about the splitting bit. Is it hardcoded by the telnet functionality that it will split after that many characters? Or is it a result of what I wrote.

Comment: It's arbitrary. You haven't processed the data into protocol data units yet, you've just read it. The code that calls this should re-assemble it, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're only getting 1448 bytes at a time is that the underlying protocols divide the transmission into packets. Frequently, this size is around 1500, and there are some bytes used for bookkeeping, so you're left with a chunk of 1448 bytes. The protocols don't guarantee that if you send X bytes in a 'single shot', that the client will receive X bytes in a single shot (e.g. a single call to the receive method).

As has been noted already in the comments above, its up to the receiving program to re-assemble these packets in a way that is meaningful to the client. In generally, you perform receives and append the data you receive to some buffer until you find an agreed-upon 'end of the block of data' marker (such as an end-of-line, new-line, carriage return, some symbol that won't appear in the data, etc.).

If the server is genuinely a telnet server--its output might be line-based (e.g. a single block of data is terminated with a 'end of line': carriage return and linefeed characters). RFC 854 may be helpful--it details the Telnet protocol as originally specified.

Comment: Addendum: Its important to understand that with socket/TCP operations, the input methods do not 'read a line', they read 'some number of bytes at a time' (in this case 1,448). This differs greatly from a typical 'read from keyboard' input method, which usually terminates on a 'line' (when the user hits enter).

Comment: Also, it is prudent to check to see if the stream has data for you to collect each iteration through. The data may not be in the stream at the time that you attempt to 'read' it.

Comment: Check it why? That's what the read does. It blocks until data is available.

Comment: Not if the socket is a non-blocking socket. On a non-blocking socket, read does not wait for the data to arrive. If there isn't any data to be read, it will return 0 (nothing read), indicating the sending program hasn't sent the data yet (or it has yet to arrive).

Answer (score 4):

You're expecting to get telnet protocol data units from the TCP layer. It just doesn't work that way. You can only extract telnet protocol data units from the code that implements the telnet protocol. The segmentation of bytes of data at the TCP layer is arbitrary and it's the responsibility of higher layers to reconstruct the protocol data units.

The behavior you are seeing is normal, and unless you're diagnosing a performance issue, you should completely ignore the way the data is split at the TCP level.